# What will be the remainder when $81(64^{25}) $ is divided by $9^4$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am unable to determine how to proceed with the question. I tried out a few steps as below -

$81 (64^{25}) / 9^4 = 81(64^{25}) / 81 * 81$

Cancelling out 81 from numerator and denominator, I get

$ = 64^{25} / 81$

This equation can be written as

$ = 8^{50} / 9^2$

$ = (9 - 1)^{50} / 9^2$

I can see I have to use Binomial Theorem to solve it further but I am confused how to do that.

Comment: $\displaystyle (1-9)^{50} = 1-50\cdot 9+\binom{50}{2}\cdot 9^2+...........+\binom{50}{50}\cdot 9^{50}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: *Start* with the binomial theorem. Write down the first two or three terms of the expansion of $(1+63)^{25}$. Because we are multiplying by $81$, we only need two terms.